# Update restrictions on Elasticsearch Object type field

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elk

I have to store documents with a single field contains a single Json object. this object has a variable depth and variable schema.
I config a mapping like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "message": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine and Elasticsearch creates and updates mapping with documents that received.
The problem is that after some updates in mapping, it rejects new documents and do not update mapping anymore. At this time I change the indices and mapping update occurred for that indies. I'm looking forward to know the right solution.

for example the first document is:

```
{
    personalInfo:{
        fistName: "tom"
    }
    moviesStatistics: {
        count: 100
    }
}
```

the second document that will update Elasticsearch mapping is:

```
{
    personalInfo:{
        fistName: "tom",
        lastName: "hanks"
    },
    moviesStatistics: {
        count: 100
    },
    education: {
        title: "a title..."
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch creates mapping with doc1 and updates it with doc2, doc3, ... until a number of documents received. After that it starts to reject every document that is not matched to the last mapping fields.

Comment: what updates in mapping? what is rejecting response messages? my first guess is you have conflict in type of fields.

Comment: Thanks for your response. for example some documents with a message field that has different inner fields but with no conflicts.

Comment: please update your question with some example and response message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm using ELK for monitoring a custom log that change by each development of an application. Filebeats send logs to Logstash and Logstash send it to ElasticSearch then kibana monitor them in a dashboard.

Comment: just fyi, it's Elasticsearch, the S is not a capital :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all I found the solution in the home page of Elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13//dynamic-field-mapping.html
We can use Dynamic mapping and simply use this mapping:

```
"mappings": {
        "dynamic": "true"
}
```

You should also change some default restrictions that mentioned here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13//mapping-settings-limit.html